# Starrocks DB - Unable to start BE service due to Seg fault

Tags: segmentation-fault, starrocks

I am trying to start the BE service and it results in a Segmentation fault.
I was able to start the FE successfully.
I tried to start the BE on 2 nodes, one where the FE service is running and also on a different node but both result in a Seg fault.

Environment -
OS - Ubuntu 22.04.3
Processor - x86

Starrocks version - 2.5.17

There is no indication of where is it failing

1. BE config file - added storage path and priority network.
   All the needed ports are free on the node.

```
$cat be/conf/be.conf

sys_log_level = INFO

be_port = 9060
webserver_port = 8040
heartbeat_service_port = 9050
brpc_port = 8060

priority_networks = 192.168.110.192/24

storage_root_path = /data/be_storage
```

2. Java installation

```
$echo $JAVA_HOME
/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64
```

I have installed openjdk-11-jdk

```
$javac -version
javac 11.0.21
```

3. Starting the BE service -

```
$./be/bin/start_be.sh 
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

4. Logs -

```
$cat be/log/be.out 
start time: Fri Jan 5 08:43:16 AM UTC 2024
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  This question seems to be a support question rather than a programming one.  Please contact the Starrocks DB devs. (Which you apparently have.)